# Making multiple models cast an ID using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am new to using the Entity Framework. I have added my Model, and I need to use two my models/tables in one View Page. So to do that I added this to my AccountViewModels.cs page:

```
  public class category_menuitem
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; }

}
```

I am trying to use Values from those two Models/Tables.

My View Page:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient
@model IEnumerable<YourGoGetterV1.Models.category_menuitem>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show Menu" - ViewBag.restaurant_id;
}

<h2>ShowMenu</h2>


<div class="jumbotron">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div><strong>@Html.DisplayFor(item1 => item.Category.Name)</strong>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(item1 => item.Category.Description)</div>
    @{ 
        using (var context = new YourGoGetterContext())
        {
            SqlParameter sa = new SqlParameter("@p0", ViewBag.restaurant_id);
            var menu_items = context.MenuItems.SqlQuery("Select * FROM MenuItems where restaurant_id = @p0", sa).ToList();
            var test = "DID IT WORK??";
        }
    }


        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowMenu(string id, int restaurant_id)
{
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    ViewBag.restaurant_id = restaurant_id;
    return View(Models.category_menuitem.ToList((object(id)));

}
```

I want to cast the ID, so that it creates a different URL for something that passes in a different ID. But I'm having two problems.

1) I can't even put in the Models.Category_menuitem.ToList() because "No overload for method 'ToList' takes 1 arguments"

2)The Models.Category_menuitem does not contain a definition for ToList.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it different. The model should contain the data you use in the view. So do your db requests in the model and give the model to the view to display the data in it. Don't do SQL requests in the view. You also should write classnames always in capital letters because of C# naming conventions.

If I understand it right you want to display a menubar or something like that with categories and each category has many menuitems?

Just create a model menuitems like this:

```
public class MenuItems {
public List<Category> Categories{get;set;}
}
```

and a model Category like this:

```
    public class Category {
public string CategoryName {get;set;}
public List<MenuItem> MenuItems {get;set;}
}
```

Fill the models with data and give the MenuItems Model to the view. In the view you can do something like:

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
    {

foreach (var menuItem in category.MenuItems)
    {

}
}
```

I hope this helps ;)

To this part of your code:

```
var menu_items = context.MenuItems.SqlQuery("Select * FROM MenuItems where restaurant_id = @p0", sa).ToList();
```

I am not sure what you wanna do. You are querying the db for data which should be already in the model or am I wrong? But if you want to use EF you would write:

```
var items = context.Menuitems.Where(m => m.restaurant_id == id).ToList();
```